# After setting npm config proxy ubuntu, npm not working

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-16.04

Npm crashed after running these two commands:

```
$ npm config set proxy http://login:pass@host:port
```

```
$ npm config set https-proxy http://login:pass@host:port
```

When I enter another command such as `npm install` or `npm build` my Terminal shows this error:

```
URIError: URI malformed
    at decodeURIComponent (native)
    at Url.parse (url.js:195:19)
    at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:84:5)
    at Object.validateUrl [as validate] (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:164:13)
    at validate (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:212:24)
    at validate (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:179:11)
    at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:101:12
    at Array.map (native)
    at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:67:15
    at Array.forEach (native)

/usr/share/npm/lib/npm.js:34
      throw new Error('npm.load() required')
      ^

Error: npm.load() required
    at Object.npm.config.get (/usr/share/npm/lib/npm.js:34:13)
    at exit (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:60:40)
    at process.errorHandler (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:178:3)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at process._fatalException (node.js:223:26)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error on running `npm install`.

The problem was in the proxy password in the `.npmrc` file. It contained the `%` symbol.

All special symbols have to be URL-encoded. See [issue #7353](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7353).

When I had changed `%` to `%25` it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (works in linux)

1. To set the proxy run:

   ```
   npm config set proxy http://username:password@host:port
   ```
2. To unset the proxy run:

   ```
   npm config set proxy null
   ```
3. To Check if the proxy is set run:

   ```
   npm config get proxy
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But the problem was in .npmrc file. When i removed username and password. Npm started working right.